# unable to reshape array into different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the following code:

```
l = -r_dot_k - sq_rt + 2*sq_rt*(npl.norm(r_rel,axis=1)<np.abs(self._radius))
l.reshape(N,1)
intercept_pt = ray_direction*l + ray_point

#r_dot_k: (25L,)
#sq_rt: (25L,)
#r_rel: (25L,3L)
#l: (25L,) #after first line
#ray_direction: (25L,3L)
#ray_point: (25L,3L)
```

There is an error for the third line saying that 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25,3) (25,)'. Since the shape of l is not correct, I add the second line to try to change the shape of l from (25L,) to (25L,1L), but it doesn't work. The shape of l before and after the second line is still (25L,). Why? How should I reshape l so that the third line can run?

Comment: I think `ray_direction*l[:,None]`, which might be same as `ray_direction*l.reshape(N,1)` if you want to use the second line, where `N = 25`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.reshape` doesn't modify `array` it returns a new array with the new shape. I think you want:

```
l = l.reashape(N, 1)
```